# MaterializeCSS: Toast scrolls to top of page

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have an ajax request when a user clicks a button. On success, it returns

```
M.toast({html: "Success"})
```

However, it scrolls to the top of the page when it shows the toast. Why does it do this?

Comment: Is it the toast that's causing the scrolling, or is your button/link appending a `#` to the URL which causes it to search for a bookmark within the page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Lmao yeah that was the problem. I used href=# to make it behave like a link.